# Конвертация чисел в строку с контактезацией?

Tags: php

доброго времени суток! 
Есть у меня 2 переменных типа "число"
`$myid` и `$iduser`,
нужно мне их сконтактировать в строку таким образом к примеру `$myid = 65` а `$iduser = 43`
сделать так, чтобы после контактизации получалась строка : 65+43

Пробую делать так: возвращает абракадабрическую ошибку( что делать??

```
$table = "(string)$myid"."+"."(string)$iduser";
```

Comment: нет <?php не забыл...

    if (isset($_POST['iduser'])) { $iduser = $_POST['iduser'];}
    if (isset($_POST['myid'])) { $myid = $_POST['myid'];}


    function table_exist($table)
    {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."` WHERE 0");
    
        $is_exist = ($res) ? true : false;

        return $is_exist;
   }



    $table = $myid"+"$iduser;

   echo ("$table");

    ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался. Просто был косяк в отправке формы - переменные не были заключены в дескрипторы!) и передавались их имена)